# in streamlit, AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'

Tags: streamlit

not sure why there is this error? From error trace, the error is st.pyplot(ax), not fig.savefig(). If I remove st..pyplot(ax). no error and fig.savefig() still works. Not sure why the error says 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'. Thanks for help.

```
import pickle

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import streamlit as st
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os

# run the commnad
# streamlit run penguins_streamlit.py

st.title("Penguin Classifier")

st.write(
    """This app uses 6 inputs to predict
     the species of penguin using a model
     built on the Palmer's Penguins dataset.
     Use the form below to get started!"""
)

password_guess = st.text_input("What is the Password?")
# if password_guess != "streamlit_is_great":
if password_guess != "start":
    st.stop()


penguin_file = st.file_uploader("Upload your own penguin data")

print('Current working')
print(os.getcwd())
if penguin_file is None:
    # rf_pickle_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"penguin_ml\\random_forest_penguin.pickle")
    # rf_pickle = open(rf_pickle_path, "rb")
    rf_pickle = open("random_forest_penguin.pickle", "rb")
    
    # map_pickle_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"penguin_ml\output_penguin.pickle")
    # map_pickle = open(map_pickle_path, "rb")
    map_pickle = open("output_penguin.pickle", "rb")

    rfc = pickle.load(rf_pickle)
    unique_penguin_mapping = pickle.load(map_pickle)
    rf_pickle.close()
    map_pickle.close()
    penguin_df = pd.read_csv("penguins.csv")
else:
    penguin_df = pd.read_csv(penguin_file)
    penguin_df = penguin_df.dropna()
    output = penguin_df["species"]
    features = penguin_df[
        [
            "island",
            "bill_length_mm",
            "bill_depth_mm",
            "flipper_length_mm",
            "body_mass_g",
            "sex",
        ]
    ]
    features = pd.get_dummies(features)
    output, unique_penguin_mapping = pd.factorize(output)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, output, test_size=0.8)
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=15)
    rfc.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = rfc.predict(x_test)
    score = round(accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test), 2)
    st.write(
        f"""We trained a Random Forest model on these data,
        it has a score of {score}! Use the
        inputs below to try out the model"""
    )

with st.form("user_inputs"):
    island = st.selectbox("Penguin Island", options=["Biscoe", "Dream", "Torgerson"])
    sex = st.selectbox("Sex", options=["Female", "Male"])
    bill_length = st.number_input("Bill Length (mm)", min_value=0)
    bill_depth = st.number_input("Bill Depth (mm)", min_value=0)
    flipper_length = st.number_input("Flipper Length (mm)", min_value=0)
    body_mass = st.number_input("Body Mass (g)", min_value=0)
    st.form_submit_button()

island_biscoe, island_dream, island_torgerson = 0, 0, 0
if island == "Biscoe":
    island_biscoe = 1
elif island == "Dream":
    island_dream = 1
elif island == "Torgerson":
    island_torgerson = 1

sex_female, sex_male = 0, 0
if sex == "Female":
    sex_female = 1
elif sex == "Male":
    sex_male = 1

new_prediction = rfc.predict(
    [
        [
            bill_length,
            bill_depth,
            flipper_length,
            body_mass,
            island_biscoe,
            island_dream,
            island_torgerson,
            sex_female,
            sex_male,
        ]
    ]
)
st.subheader("Predicting Your Penguin's Species:")
prediction_species = unique_penguin_mapping[new_prediction][0]
st.write(f"We predict your penguin is of the {prediction_species} species")
st.write(
    """We used a machine learning
    (Random Forest) model to predict the
    species, the features used in this
    prediction are ranked by relative
    importance below."""
)

if penguin_file is None:
    st.image("feature_importance.png")
else:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.barplot(x=rfc.feature_importances_, y=features.columns)
    plt.title("Which features are the most important for species prediction?")
    plt.xlabel("Importance")
    plt.ylabel("Feature")
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig("feature_importance.png")
    st.pyplot(ax)

st.write(
    """Below are the histograms for each
continuous variable separated by penguin species.
The vertical line represents the inputted value."""
)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\streamlit\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 535, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\penguin_ml\penguins_streamlit.py", line 134, in <module>
    st.pyplot(ax)
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\streamlit\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\metrics_util.py", line 397, in wrapped_func
    result = non_optional_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\streamlit\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\pyplot.py", line 109, in pyplot
    marshall(
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\streamlit\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\pyplot.py", line 161, in marshall
    fig.savefig(image, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```